# Add Json data to Django model automatically and only once

Tags: python, json, django, model, no-op

I created a model class and a method that saves Json data to that model.

**models.py**:

```
class Object(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)


 @classmethod
    def save_json_data_to_model(cls):
        with open('data.json', encoding='utf8') as file:
            data = json.load(file)
            for obj in data:
                    Object(
                        name=obj['name'],
                        address=obj['Street']).save()
```

I want the json data to be populated in the model automatically and not call the method "save_json_data_to_model(cls)" manually. What is the best way to achieve this?

I tried something like this:

**views.py:**

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
Obj.save_json_data_to_model()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should make this a data migration: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/migrations/#data-migrations